# position independed cose-call printf-assembly

Tags: assembly

Is

```
  call printf
```

could be used in position independed code?
On the one hand, call is relative, in the other hand printf is a library function.
If the answer is not, why? in the link stage the code of printf not copied to the file I write? (and then it seems to me ok).

Answer (score 1):

you can do a relative FAR call (inter-modular call) using the [GOT](http://bottomupcs.sourceforge.net/csbu/x3824.htm), which will hold the absolute address to `printf`, then to call `printf`, one would perform something like `CALL [GOT + printf_index * sizeof(ptr)]` (this expression will be folded down to a constant during assembly/compilation).

The alternate, but totally terrible way is to merge the CRT function that you are using into your shared library/binary (MSVC calls this static linkage), but ofc this bloat the binary and leaves it non-future friendly, and thus open to possibly undiscovered bugs in the CRT that was statically linked to.